# UIColor of tab bar items unselected and changing tabbar color

Tags: ios, ios8, uitabbar, uicolor, uitabbaritem

I see by using the setTintColor on a tabBar I can change the selected item color.

How do I change the unselected tabBarItem color and text?

If I can't change it easily, what is the default gray color used (in RGB)?

Thanks.

Comment: just use the digital color meter application standard on every Mac to get the RGB. For the other questions, I don't have a better answer than create your own view/tabBar

Comment: Yeah I wish there was an easy wahy like tintColor for unselected tab bar items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use images for tabBarItems.

To set unselected image use:

```
[tabBarItem setImage:(UIImage*)image]
```

To set selected image use:

```
[tabBarItem setSelectedImage:(UIImage*)image]
```

Text in tabBarItem is title of viewController thats connected to that tabBarItem.

You can find good icons for tabBar online, here's good one: https://icons8.com/

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5.1, iOS 13**

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {

let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.clear]
tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance

            } else {
                //Code for below iOS 13.0, which I'm currently looking into too.

            }
```